# keyboard sequence for Magnify in version 8?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, keyboard

It used to be that you could find a Magnify item in the Format menu of the Mathematica front-end, at the very bottom if I remember correctly. You could get at the item in Windows by a keyboard sequence like `Alt-R`, `M`, then a number.  Mac probably had something similar.

This was really useful for mouse avoiders like me. That little tiny drop menu in the extreme lower right of a notebook is annoying to catch with a mouse on highest-speed setting, which you need on a high-def screen with 1920 or 2560 pixels width. My mouse movements end up looking like a plot of a strange attractor swirling around the target!

I haven't been able to find the Magnify menu item in Mathematica 8 nor any other keyboard shortcut for notebook-magnify in the Mathematica documentation center. Would be grateful for anyone pointing out any means for accessing notebook magnify from the keyboard.

Comment: Have you tried Alt-W M ?

Comment: Ahh, thanks.  That was it!  Post as answer and I'll mark it so (just proves I'm blind, and that's why I need Magnify!)

Comment: Guess why I knew it !

Comment: Any idea for the mac version of this? On a related issue, would you know how to change the default size of the help window?

Comment: @chris No and no, sorry. I will check Linux at home tonight.

Comment: @chris Same for Linux, Alt-W M.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyboard sequence is `Alt-W M` on both Windows and Linux. This will open a drop down menu where you can select the magnification.